# Slow query with dependent queries in JOIN

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-optimization

I have following DB scheme:
[image: scheme of my DB]
There are thousands of "cars" in table "e_tram". 
Each car can have more records with info about type of car in table "e_vozy_typy". In table "e_vozy_dopravci" there are info about owner and in "e_vozy_razeni" and "e_vozy_evc" there are information about car registration etc. 
In column "poradi" has the newest record max value and the oldest record min value (min value is typically 1).

I want to write SELECT, which returns for each car the newest information from other tables.

I tried following:

```
SELECT
    et.id

    aktevt.ntyp,
    aktevt.typ, 

    akteve.evc,
    akteve.ind,

    aktevr.razeni,

FROM e_tram AS et

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT idvozu, MAX(poradi) AS aktporadi
    FROM e_vozy_typy AS evt
    GROUP BY evt.idvozu
)   AS evt
    ON et.id = evt.idvozu

INNER JOIN e_vozy_typy AS aktevt
    ON et.id = aktevt.idvozu AND evt.aktporadi = aktevt.poradi


INNER JOIN (
    SELECT idvozu, MAX(poradi) AS aktporadi
    FROM e_vozy_dopravci AS evd
    GROUP BY evd.idvozu
)   AS evd
    ON et.id = evd.idvozu

INNER JOIN e_vozy_dopravci AS aktevd
    ON et.id = aktevd.idvozu AND evd.aktporadi = aktevd.poradi


INNER JOIN (
    SELECT idvuzdopravce, MAX(poradi) AS aktporadi
    FROM e_vozy_evca AS eve
    GROUP BY eve.idvuzdopravce
)   AS eve
    ON aktevd.id = eve.idvuzdopravce

INNER JOIN e_vozy_evca AS akteve
    ON aktevd.id = akteve.idvuzdopravce 
        AND eve.aktporadi = akteve.poradi


LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT idvuzdopravce, MAX(poradi) AS aktporadi
    FROM e_vozy_razeni AS evr
    GROUP BY evr.idvuzdopravce
)   AS evr
    ON aktevd.id = evr.idvuzdopravce

LEFT JOIN e_vozy_razeni AS aktevr
    ON aktevd.id = aktevr.idvuzdopravce 
        AND evr.aktporadi = aktevr.poradi


GROUP BY et.id

ORDER BY akteve.evc, akteve.ind, et.id
```

Despite of indexes on all columns id (+ foreign key-columns) and poradi this query takes about 90 second. I can see in EXPLAIN that MySQL doesnt use indexes in dependent queries in JOINs. Is there any solution to do this effectively?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the data, but you may need to denormalize the database to increase performance and provide a linkable index. In your e_tram table add in max_field columns for each of the child tables you are joining, then decide how you are going to populate those fields. You could either run an update for each field before the main query is run, or a trigger to update a particular field when I child table gets changed.